# RecyclerView in a scrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-recyclerview

When scrolling up to the first position item in RecyclerView, can ScrollView continue to scroll up? Here is the code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/margin_10dp_in_w1024dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
```

Comment: That is not the default behavior

Comment: so I should custom a layout_behavior?

Comment: I do not really understand what you want to achieve there? can you explain it in your question

Answer (score 0):

Having two scrollviews that scroll in the same direction is not possible , try to rethink your UI .

You can :

- Use recyclerview to handle diffrent types of views , so that you no more need another scrollview .
- Use parallax views in coordinatorLayout to show information every time you reach first position .